# Graphics on a bootloader

Tags: c, assembly, boot

Managed to create a simple bootloader... and with VESA 2.0 I managed to change the resolution to 1024x768x32, also managed to setup a Linear Frame Buffer... Where can I find tutorials for using the frame buffer? Like lets say to display a picture before it finishes to load?

So far I saw one sample on how to "draw" an ipod...called CdPod

Comment: what sort of hardware are you trying to boot?

Comment: @Fredrick: Hi I am also creating bootloader created first stage to display "Hello World". I want to load second stage from first stage bootloader. Can you please refer me a link which can show me how achieve it? Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065370/how-to-load-second-stage-boot-loader-from-first-stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the address of the linear framebuffer all you need to do is to copy the raw image data to it's location.

Comment: Is it really that hard? memcpy (video_address, image_address, 1280*768*32); should do the trick.

Comment: I managed to find how to use the lfb from singularity os, even though the code was in c# it can easily be ported to c

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I never tried to code a bootloader however maybe you can find your way looking at the source code of [XOSL](http://www2.arnes.si/~fkomar/xosl.org/download.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the syslinux project on syslinux.zytor.com - you should find some code for it in that project

Answer (score 1):

Grub? It's open source, you may check how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's for x86 architecture?
If true, then look for old DOS tutorials for working with video memory.
May be something like that: "[Farpointers and video in DJGPP](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~walpole/325/DJ_GRAPH.txt)"

Really, all new is well forgotten old :-)